# d3plus: how to flip order of drawn boxplots?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, d3plus

I am using this code for a d3 viz (Box Plot and Whiskers):

```
var ODGCostsChart = d3plus.viz()
    .container("#my_viz")
    .data(dataNoMinMax)
    .type("box")
    .id("measure")
    .x("provider")
    .y("deviation")
    .draw();
```

where each row of my data is either:

```
{deviation: round(d.value,2), provider: 'This', measure: d.metric}
```

or:

```
{deviation: round(d.value_others,2), provider: 'All', measure: d.metric}
```

I would like the resulting visualization to have two boxplots side-by-side, one for "This" provider, and another for "All" providers right next to it. No matter how I try, though, I keep getting the boxplots with "All" preceding "This":
[image]

For the life of me I don't know how to flip the order of the boxplots in the drawing. I have gone through the [documentation](https://github.com/alexandersimoes/d3plus/wiki/Visualizations) but I am not sure whether it's even possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the `order` function on your viz like bellow ?

```
var ODGCostsChart = d3plus.viz()
    .container("#my_viz")
    .data(dataNoMinMax)
    .order({sort: 'asc' }) // or {sort: 'desc'}
    .type("box")
    .id("measure")
    .x("provider")
    .y("deviation")
    .draw();
```

You can see other options for this order function [here](https://github.com/alexandersimoes/d3plus/wiki/Visualizations#order)

Comment: This didn't work either, eventually what did the trick was:

`.order({"value": "provider"})`

even though I don't see how "This" got ordered before "All"

Answer (score 0):

Eventually what did the trick was:

`.order({"value": "provider"})`

even though I don't see how "This" got ordered before "All"

Comment: I assume it's because it has a value lower than "All".